# MySQL PHP with sort of future date

Tags: php, mysql, date, sorting

I am trying to pull results from my table that have either type 1, 2 or 3 and each event has a date. I am trying to only show future events and sort them. The code below is kinda working, with the exception of sorting by date, it is only sorting based upon the order the events were entered into the database.

```
$sql = " SELECT * 
           FROM fitness 
          WHERE type = '3' 
            AND date >= CURRENT_DATE() 
         ORDER BY 'date' ASC";
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have 'date' in single quotes, which means the literal text string date.

Take the single quotes off.

Also, you don't say whether your date column is a `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` item.  If it's a `DATE` item there won't be much to distinguish your events if many of them have the same date.

Finally, `DATE` is a reserved word. You may be baffling MySQL by using it for a column name.  I would change it if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM fitness 
        WHERE type = '3' 
        AND date >= CURRENT_DATE() 
        ORDER BY date ASC";
```

Notice no single quote around date. If that does not work, try the following.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM fitness 
        WHERE type = '3' 
        AND `date` >= CURRENT_DATE() 
        ORDER BY `date` ASC";
```

In this case, the back tick character ` is used instead of the single quote. This is because "date" is a reserved word.